# How to trap Escape key during ADODB SELECT (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, adodb

I have some VBA code in Excel that sets up an ADODB connection and runs a SELECT query to an Access database, using `rst.Open` (where `rst` is an `ADODB.RecordSet`). It all works well. I have some standard error handling in just about every routine in the code and that all works well too, handling errors gracefully with a call to `MsgBox` and so on.

My problem is that if the user presses ESCAPE during the SELECT (ie while the `rst.Open` is executing) then Excel/VBA seems to ***completely ignore*** the error handling and displays the standard `Code execution has been interrupted` with `Continue/End/Debug/Help` buttons, as if there were no error handling at all. As if to confirm this, if I click on "Debug" in this error dialogue, it sends me to the line directly ***after*** the `rst.Open` line (highlighted in yellow as usual); if I then go to the VBE Immediate Window and type `print Err.number` it returns zero -- ie no error -- instead of the standard error 18 that I would have expected.

Note that one of the first things the program does when it starts executing is `Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler`, but that, plus the `On Error Goto ErrHandler` in this routine, seem to be completely ignored.

Other things I have tried:

- Disable the ESC key using `Application.OnKey "{ESC}",""` and restore it using `Application.OnKey "{ESC}"` straight after the `rst.Open` -- when the user presses ESCAPE then Debug it is this second line that is highlighted!
- Using `Application.Interactive = False` just before the `rst.Open` and restoring straight afterwards.
- The code is called from a userform, and I tried inserting `Userform_KeyDown` and looking for `vbKeyEscape`.

None of these worked. It's almost as if the `rst.Open` operates "outside" the Excel VBA environment and the ESCAPE is being pressed in the "ADODB" environment, and ADODB reports back to Excel that there has been an interruption.

Can anyone help please? I am not necessarily wanting to prevent users interrupting a SELECT (since that would probably be ill-advised!), but I want to be able to gracefully handle the interrupt without the standard ugly message that gives them the chance to get into the VBA.

I don't think it would help to show you the code, but here it is anyway:

```
Private Sub RunSelectQuery(ByRef rst As ADODB.Recordset, _
    ByVal strSql As String, ByRef cnn As ADODB.Connection)
Dim booEof As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    rst.Open strSql, cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

    booEof = rst.EOF

ErrHandler:        ' -- Error handling and Routine termination.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then If DspErr() Then Stop: Resume Else End
End Sub
```

As I said, this works perfectly provided the user does not press ESCAPE during the rst.Open statement; if they do press ESCAPE then the ugly error message appears, and when you click on Debug it highlights the line `booEof =`. That line, by the way, could be anything -- I have inserted other lines there, and the Debug button always takes me to the next executable line below the `rst.Open` line.

Running with Office Professional Plus 2016, Windows 10.

Comment: Accepted answer from EvR -- thanks very much. It never occurred to me that EnableCancelKey would have its status changed like that, so didn't look deeply enough into the documentation there. I have clicked on the tick, upvoted it -- is there anything else I need to do? (S.O. newbie)

Comment: No, Good clear question, with the right tags, welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msdn:

> The EnableCancelKey property is always reset to xlInterrupt whenever
>   Microsoft Excel returns to the idle state and there's no code running.
>   To trap or disable cancellation in your procedure, you must explicitly
>   change the EnableCancelKey property every time the procedure is
>   called.